# Visual Studio like code snippets in Rider

Tags: rider

Does anyone know if the JetBrains Rider IDE supports kind of "code snippets"? I usually have a snippet in Visual Studio for creating NUnit test cases, like:

```cs
[Test]
[Description("Some description")]
[MaxTime(1000)]
public void Test()
{
#region Arrange
#endregion

#region Assert
#endregion

#region Act
#endregion
}
```

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Yes, there is.

In Rider, it is called **Live Templates**.

- Open menu ***File > Settings***.
- In the Settings window, expand ***Editor > Live Templates***.
- Then select the language you want. Let's say C#.
- The settings window shows the list of shortcuts.
- Click the ***New Template*** icon on the right.[image: Settings]
- In the ***Shortcut*** field, define the keyword you want to use to trigger it.
- You can select any other shortcut to have an example.
- Save your changes.
- Go to the editor and type the "shortcut".
- Rider will create the code for you.

Keep in mind that Live Templates use a different syntax from Visual Studio Code Snippets, so you can check this page - [Predefined Live Templates for C#](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/Reference__Templates_Explorer__Live_Templates_CSHARP.html) - for further reference.

Comment: Referencing https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/oauth?state=%2Fissue%2FRIDER-548 for pending feature of creating C# Live Templates in Rider

Comment: Would it be possible for you to update this? Most of the terms from step 3 are different today. ie. Abbreviation now says shortcut. Also; There is no Expand With. In step 10 you mention a key - What is this key you refer to?